# Honeyd Logging Issue

Tags: honeypot

I have a question regarding the `Honeyd` logging . I am using Raspberry pi Wheezy Raspbian ...

I am using the `-l` flag as described on the website of the Honeyd. 
but the problem is I could not found that where the logs are being stored I cant find them ..

```
$ sudo honeyd -d -f honeyd.conf -l /usr/share/honeyd/scripts/logs/honeyd.txt
```

When I checked the `honeyd.txt` file, its always empty

It will be very nice and the help will be highly appreciated .

Regards
OY

Comment: Having never used `honeyd`, I can think of 2 general possibilities: 1) `honeyd` has not written to its log file yet (which, if `-d` is short for `--debug`) is unlikely. 2) `honeyd` does not have the right permissions to overwrite the log file.